# Display the max-length of entity-field in template of cakephp 3.x

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a cakephp 3.x project with a form containing the input-field "description". The model has a maxLength for this field of 160 characters defined:

```
$validator
    ->allowEmpty('description')
    ->add('description', 'length', [
        'rule' => ['maxLength', 160],
        'message' => 'Products description cannot be longer than 160 characters'
    ]);
```

In my template I have a small javascript-script that shows the user how many of the 160 characters he has already used `140 of 160 characters used`.

The 160 is right now hard-coded. Is it possible to get this value from my table or entity? Something like `$product->geMaxLength('description');`?

Comment: Have you looked at the [schema system section of the manual](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/schema-system.html)?

Comment: No, I hadn't looked at it before. However this section does not provide the answer, because the max-length is only in the validator and not (yet) in the schema definition.

Comment: Ah, I had assumed that the schema included this limit as well, like `varchar(160)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if is the right or the best way to do this but you can retrieve your `Validator` from the `Table` object in the `Controller` and then get the `ValidatorSet` and the `ValidatorRule` for your field

I assume here that your model name here is `Products`

your `ProductsController.php`:

```
$maxLength = $this->Products
    ->getValidator()       // gets the validator for the ProductsTable
    ->field('description') // gets a ValidationSet for a field
    ->rule('length')       // gets the Rule for the length 
    ->get('pass');         // gets the value of the maxLength
```

then you can pass thuis value to the view

```
$this->set('maxLength', $maxLength);
```

so that you can use that value in your view

```
$this->Form->control('description', ['label' => 'max '.$maxLength.' chars']);
```

API reference

[getValidator()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.5/class-Cake.Validation.ValidatorAwareInterface.html#_getValidator)

[field()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.5/class-Cake.Validation.Validator.html#_field)

[rule()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.5/class-Cake.Validation.ValidationSet.html#_rule)

[get()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.5/class-Cake.Validation.ValidationRule.html#_get)